# How to properly reference an external web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have my main web.config file and another one like:

```
web.config
web.logging.config
```

The web.logging.config has:

```
<configuration>
  <configSection>
      <section name="log4net" ... />
   </configSection>

   <log4net> ....</lognet>

</configuration>
```

I just want to confirm, if I don't somehow reference this web.logging.config file from my web.config file, it will not automatically pick it up will it?

How would I reference this file then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking anything specific to log4net, that is possible to have log4net configuration file as a separate file.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile ="MyLog4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```